# Docker fails to starts after automated installation

Tags: bash, docker, debian

As a part of VPS creation, I have a script that creates a default user, secures SSH etc. One step, however, keeps failing and that's the installation of docker. I minimized the script to handle only docker installation and it still fails. Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
{
    export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION="1.24.1"

    apt-get install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
    add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
    apt-get -y update
    apt-get -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io

    curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
    curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/docker/compose/$DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION/contrib/completion/bash/docker-compose -o /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose

} > /init-script.log 2> /init-script-err.log
```

And this is a trimmed content of the error log

```
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-03-26 18:00:35 UTC; 9ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3216 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3216 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

When I check `journalctl` it seems the underlying issue is related to socket unavailability `failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd` when starting the `docker.service`.

```
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Starting containerd container runtime...
-- Subject: A start job for unit containerd.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit containerd.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 425.
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd-udevd[220]: Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring.
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Started containerd container runtime.
-- Subject: A start job for unit containerd.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit containerd.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 425.
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.204032978Z" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision=7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429 version=1.2.13
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.205059960Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.content.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.205311948Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.205638264Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs" error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.205845252Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.208866659Z" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs" error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64\n": exit status 1"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.211076859Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.211375337Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.211700190Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.212088689Z" level=info msg="skip loading plugin "io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.212242393Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.212411125Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter btrfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.212551115Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter aufs in metadata plugin" error="modprobe aufs failed: "modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.0-8-amd64\n": exit status 1"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.212710676Z" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter zfs in metadata plugin" error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215500601Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.differ.v1.walking"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215535042Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215577789Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.containers-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215594004Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.content-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215607955Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.diff-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215624419Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.images-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215639471Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.leases-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215655963Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.namespaces-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215669565Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.snapshots-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215687040Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215792942Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.runtime.v2.task"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.215857103Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.monitor.v1.cgroups"..." type=io.containerd.monitor.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.216185682Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.service.v1.tasks-service"..." type=io.containerd.service.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.216211500Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.restart"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217511730Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.containers"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217534636Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.content"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217547186Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.diff"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217556095Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.events"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217572710Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.healthcheck"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217583819Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.images"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217593802Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.leases"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217604004Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.namespaces"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.217614317Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.internal.v1.opt"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.218026907Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.snapshots"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.218049421Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.tasks"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.218064133Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.version"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.218076770Z" level=info msg="loading plugin "io.containerd.grpc.v1.introspection"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.218306294Z" level=info msg=serving... address="/run/containerd/containerd.sock"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 containerd[3085]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:34.218323197Z" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.014799s"
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 groupadd[3141]: group added to /etc/group: name=docker, GID=998
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 groupadd[3141]: group added to /etc/gshadow: name=docker
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 groupadd[3141]: new group: name=docker, GID=998
Mar 26 18:00:34 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reloading.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 472.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[3216]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:35.644035999Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[3216]: failed to load listeners: no sockets found via socket activation: make sure the service was started by systemd
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit docker.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 26 18:00:35 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 472 and the job result is failed.
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit docker.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A stop job for unit docker.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 473 and the job result is done.
```

Then the system attempts to start `docker.socket` which launches successfully.

```
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 474.
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Reached target Network is Online.
-- Subject: A start job for unit network-online.target has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit network-online.target has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 521.
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Listening on Docker Socket for the API.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.socket has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 474.
```

And is followed by an attempt to start `docker.service` again, which now finishes successfully as well.

```
Mar 26 18:00:37 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.service has begun execution.
--
-- The job identifier is 473.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.027461667Z" level=info msg="Starting up"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 audit[4193]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=4193 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1585245638.085:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="docker-default" pid=4193 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.092587890Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.095092114Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.095416449Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.095906885Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.104124475Z" level=info msg="parsed scheme: \"unix\"" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.107066961Z" level=info msg="scheme \"unix\" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.107394704Z" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.107561449Z" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to \"pick_first\"" module=grpc
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-check\x2doverlayfs\x2dsupport420610117-merged.mount: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit var-lib-docker-check\x2doverlayfs\x2dsupport420610117-merged.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.194551478Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.194995719Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.195206982Z" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.195572472Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd-udevd[220]: Network interface NamePolicy= disabled on kernel command line, ignoring.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 kernel: bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 kernel: Bridge firewalling registered
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 kernel: Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.449529108Z" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd-udevd[4216]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v240'.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd-udevd[4216]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.552102196Z" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: var-lib-docker-overlay2-opaque\x2dbug\x2dcheck002229522-merged.mount: Succeeded.
-- Subject: Unit succeeded
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- The unit var-lib-docker-overlay2-opaque\x2dbug\x2dcheck002229522-merged.mount has successfully entered the 'dead' state.
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.583939094Z" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=afacb8b7f0 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 version=19.03.8
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 dockerd[4160]: time="2020-03-26T18:00:38.584331232Z" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 26 18:00:38 debian-1cpu-1gb-de-fra1 systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: A start job for unit docker.service has finished successfully
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: https://www.debian.org/support
--
-- A start job for unit docker.service has finished successfully.
--
-- The job identifier is 473.
```

When I run the exact same script from terminal once I connect to the VPS via `ssh` everything runs without a hassle.

**Edit:** I checked the logs when executing this script manually from terminal and indeed the services seem to be started in the correct order

1. `containerd.service`
2. `docker.socket`
3. `docker.service`

Comment: Hello, did you found a way to start it? Been having similar problems.

Comment: @nazar nope, I haven't spent more time on it